# How to create a price compare app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

What is the best solution to scrape many prices from many different websites?
Is it possible to scrape prices realtime? If yes how?

Comment: You should try to narrow the scope of your question. It's very broad in its current form so you probably won't get any helpful or direct answers.

Comment: I am open for answers. Detailed answer is not needed. I want an idea of how to create a price compare app.

Comment: PostgreSQL vs. MySQL is a pretty fine distinction that sometimes depends on hosting requirements, for example. Depending on where you want to scrape data from, different tools will be best suited. I'm with Pan Thomakos, think about narrowing down your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if it is still being maintained, but I've found scRUBYt to be very useful when it comes to scraping.   http://scrubyt.rubyforge.org